# SQL sum the number of satisfied conditions and compare with other column

Tags: sql, sqlite, where-clause, sql-like

I want to check for three columns if a certain condition holds. Next, I want to sum these three booleans and check whether they are the same as a value in a fourth column.

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN column1 LIKE 'D%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS bool1
       SUM(CASE WHEN column2 LIKE 'D%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS bool2
       SUM(CASE WHEN column3 LIKE 'D%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS bool3
FROM table
WHERE bool1 + bool2 + bool3 = column4
```

This gives an error however. How should I change the query?

Comment: what's your dbms? mysql <> sqlite

Comment: It makes no sense to compare a sum across all records against the single `column4`.  Sample data would help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregate function `SUM()` operates on all values of a column, so it does not make sense to compare it to a specific value of another column.

I suspect that you want something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE (column1 LIKE 'D%') + (column2 LIKE 'D%') + (column3 LIKE 'D%') = column4
```

Each of the boolean expressions `columnX LIKE 'D%'` evaluates to `0` for `false` and `1` for `true`.

If there are `null`s in the columns change to:

```
WHERE COALESCE(column1 LIKE 'D%', 0) + 
      COALESCE(column2 LIKE 'D%', 0) + 
      COALESCE(column3 LIKE 'D%', 0) = column4
```